# If $G$ is bipartite and does not have $K_{3,3}$ as a topological minor, then $G$ is planar.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Prove or disprove: If $G$ is bipartite and does not have $K_{3,3}$ as
>   a topological minor, then $G$ is planar.

Comment: So another way to do this is to show that if $G$ is a bipartite graph and does not have a $K_{3,3}$ minor then it can not have a $K_5$ minor. This would imply $G$ is planar by wagner's theorem we have $G$ is planar.

Comment: @Eoin Yeah, we should definitely evoke Wagner's theorem for this one.

Comment: But how to show that if G is bipartite and does not have topological minor K3,3, then it has no K5 as topological minor?

Answer (score 2):

This is *not true*, and a counterexample is the graph $K_5$ with each edge subdivided once.

The thought process is that this might not be true, so let's start with a small graph that is nonplanar but doesn't have $K_{3,3}$ as a topological minor. The graph $K_5$ is the natural choice here. Then we can "make $K_5$ bipartite" by subdividing each edge once (this is a nice idea that works for any graph). We can show pretty easily that the resulting graph is still nonplanar, and still doesn't have $K_{3,3}$ as a topological minor (because it has too few vertices of degree at least three).